# R: how to add labels/columns to contingency table?

Tags: r

Say that I have 2 vectors: `x <- ['Y', 'N', 'Y', 'N', 'Y']`, and `y <- [1,1,0,1,1]` (this is just a representation, not r code). I would like to get a contingency table in R by calling `table(x,y)`. This will give me a 2 x 2 contingency table with column names as "0", "1", and row names as "Y", "N". However, when `y <- [1,1,1,1,1]`, the function call `table(x,y)` will give me a 2 x 1 contingency table with only 1 column name as "1", and 2 row names as "Y", "N". How can I force `table()` to give me a 2 x 2 table with "0","1" as columns and "Y","N" as rows in this case? Or can I manually insert a column into the resulting table?

Comment: @bunk That's a simple answer! I am new to R so I don't know "factor". Could you write that as an answer? I will accept it.

Comment: x <- ['Y', 'N', 'Y', 'N', 'Y'] is wrong in R. Should be x <- c('Y', 'N', 'Y', 'N', 'Y')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert `y` to a factor with `levels` set to contain the other possible values `y` can take.  Factors are commonplace in R, and are basically just integer vectors with character labels.

```
table(x, factor(y, levels=0:1))
# x   0 1
#   N 0 2
#   Y 0 3
```

It may be worth noting that you can use the levels to format the table output as well.  For example, if you wanted the "1" column first, and "Y" before "N"

```
table(factor(x, levels=c("Y","N")), factor(y, levels=1:0))
```